# ¿Como insertar que me diga ,los caracteres de una palabra?

Tags: javascript, html5

se que la pregunta parece sencilla (y quizá lo sea?)pero no se hacer funcionar el contador de caracteres dentro de otra función para que me lo saque en la ventana dinámica de mi programa. Adjunto el link que lleva al codigo de la funcion: https://jsfiddle.net/Fostrop/961tod7p/2/

edicion: Adjunto el codigo que quiero introducir.

```
  my_window.document.write(nombre.chrAt(nombre.length-1));
```

Y lo quiero introducir en esta parte del codigo y hacer que funcione:

```
 my_window = window.open("",
    "mywindow", "status=1,height=400,width=800,left=600,location=yes,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,titlebar=yes,top=300" );

  my_window.document.write('Bienvenido ');
  my_window.document.write(nombre, '<br>');
  my_window.document.write('Naciste un feliz:', '');
  my_window.document.write(dia_de_nacimiento,' del ');
  my_window.document.write(mes,' del año ');
  my_window.document.write(ano,'<br>');

  my_window.document.write('<br><b>',"Boletin de ejercicios tema 3",'</b><br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 1",'<br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 2",'<br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 4",'<br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 5",'<br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 6",'<br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 7",'<br>');
    
  my_window.document.write(nombre.chrAt(nombre.length-1));
                          
  return my_window;
}
```

El código ejecutable

```js
var nombre;
var edad;
nombre = prompt('Ingrese su nombre y apellidos', '');
dia_de_nacimiento = prompt('Dia de nacimiento?');
mes = prompt('mes?');
ano = prompt('ano');


function abrir() {

  my_window = window.open("",
    "mywindow", "status=1,height=400,width=800,left=600,location=yes,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,titlebar=yes,top=300" );

  my_window.document.write('Bienvenido ');
  my_window.document.write(nombre, '<br>');
  my_window.document.write('Naciste un feliz:', '');
  my_window.document.write(dia_de_nacimiento,' del ');
  my_window.document.write(mes,' del año ');
  my_window.document.write(ano,'<br>');

  my_window.document.write('<br><b>',"Boletin de ejercicios tema 3",'</b><br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 1",'<br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 2",'<br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 4",'<br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 5",'<br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 6",'<br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 7",'<br>');
    
  my_window.document.write(nombre.chrAt(nombre.length-1));
                          
  return my_window;
}

var unawindow = abrir()
unawindow.document.write('<br><b>', 'Hola de nuevo', '</b><br>');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<html>   
<head> 
    <title> 
        Window prompt() Method 
    </title> 
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/mensaje.js"></script>
</head>  
<body> 
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Cuál contador de caracteres?? Si estas refiriéndote a una parte de tu código, debes poner esa parte acá

Comment: podrías agregar el código en cuestión dentro de la pregunta? Así es mas fácil ayudarte

Comment: No me deja meter tanto codigo y no se como explicarlo sin poner el codigo entero

Comment: @Jose se agrega en fragmento de código |<>| ya lo agregue en una edición espero sea aprobado.

Comment: @UrielManzano donde lo agregaste?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/243187 pero no la puedes ver porque no ha sido aprobada por miembros confiables de la comunidad, edítalo tu dale en editar a tu publicación y click en el icon |<>| ahí te va salir lo mismo que aparece en el link que en ttps://jsfiddle.net/Fostrop/961tod7p/2/ solo pasalo al fragmento.

Comment: Mira ahora @UrielManzano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jose Desde el fragmento manda error al abrir la ventana que se crea, para probarlo copia este javascript y en https://jsfiddle.net/Fostrop/961tod7p/2/ prueba
[image: Resultado]

```js
var nombre;
var edad;
nombre = prompt('Ingrese su nombre y apellidos', '');
dia_de_nacimiento = prompt('Dia de nacimiento?');
mes = prompt('mes?');
ano = prompt('ano');


function abrir() {

  my_window = window.open("",
    "mywindow", "status=1,height=400,width=800,left=600,location=yes,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,titlebar=yes,top=300" );

  my_window.document.write('Bienvenido ');
  my_window.document.write(nombre, '<br>');
  my_window.document.write('Naciste un feliz:', '');
  my_window.document.write(dia_de_nacimiento,' del ');
  my_window.document.write(mes,' del año ');
  my_window.document.write(ano,'<br>');

  my_window.document.write('<br><b>',"Boletin de ejercicios tema 3",'</b><br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 1",'<br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 2",'<br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 4",'<br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 5",'<br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 6",'<br>',
                          "U3 Tarea 7",'<br>');
    
  my_window.document.write('usando charAt: '+nombre.charAt(nombre.length-1)+'<br>');
  var nombreCaracteres = nombre.split('');
  my_window.document.write('usando split uriel tiene:'+nombre.split('')+'<br>');
  for(let i=0;i<nombreCaracteres.length;i++){
    my_window.document.write('nombre: ['+i+']: '+nombreCaracteres[i]+'<br>');
  }
                          
  return my_window;
}

var unawindow = abrir()
unawindow.document.write('<br><b>', 'Hola de nuevo', '</b><br>');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<html>   
<head> 
    <title> 
        Window prompt() Method 
    </title> 
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/mensaje.js"></script>
</head>  
<body> 
</body>  
</html>
```